# Missing template error - when layout exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionview

For whatever reason i cannot figure out why i keep getting this error. On a fresh log it is display 8 times, which is very strange.

I am running WEBrick in a production environment i've setup locally. But i receive the same error in my actual production environment running Puma on AWS.

```
ruby 2.1.4p265
rails 4.2.7.1
```

stacktrace

```
Error during failsafe response: Missing template errors/internal_server_error, 
application/internal_server_error with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:png], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby]}. Searched in:
  * "~/Rails/ReturnLabel/return_label/app/views"
  * "~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@return_disposition/gems/devise-3.5.5/app/views"
```

app/views/errors

```
$ ls app/views/errors/
./                              _error.html.erb                 internal_server_error.html.erb  no_label.html.erb               unsupported_country.html.erb
../                             expired_order.html.erb          invalid.html.erb                not_found.html.erb
```

errors_controller.rb

```
class ErrorsController < ApplicationController
  def expired_order
    @error = :expired_order
    render(status: 503)
  end
  def unsupported_country
    @error = :unsupported_country
    render(status: 503)
  end
  def invalid
    @error = :invalid
    render(status: 400)
  end
  def not_found
    @error = :not_found
    render(status: 404)
  end
  def internal_server_error
    @error = :internal_server_error
    render(status: 500)
  end
  def no_label
    @error = :no_label
    render(status: 503)
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
 match '/404', to: 'errors#not_found', as: 'not_found', via: :all
 match '/500', to: 'errors#internal_server_error', as: 'internal_server_error', via: :all
 match '/unsupported_country', to: 'errors#unsupported_country', via: :all
 match '/expired_order', to: 'errors#expired_order', via: :all
 match '/invalid', to: 'errors#invalid', via: :all
 match '/no_label', to: 'errors#no_label', via: :all
 ...
 # END OF FILE
 match '*path', to: 'errors#not_found', via: :all
```

View code

internal_server_error.html.erb

```
<header class="header-span-single-line styled">
  <div class="text-center animated shake">
    <span><%= t('error.header.title') %></span>
    <br>
  </div>
</header>
<div class="container animated bounceInUp">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
      <%= render 'error' %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

_error.html.erb

```
<% error_text = t("error.#{@error}") %>
<h1><%= error_text[:title] %></h1>
<p class="text-white"><%= error_text[:body] %></p>
<hr/>
<p><strong><%= t('error.contact.title') %></strong></p>
<ul class="list-padding">
  <li class="list-unstyled">
    <p class="cs-p"><%= t('error.contact.phone') %></p>
  </li>
  <li class="list-unstyled">
    <p class="cs-p"><%= t('error.contact.email.title') %>
      <a class="branded-link branded-link-dark" target="_blank" href="<%= t('error.contact.email.href') %>"><%= t('error.contact.email.value') %></a>
    </p>
  </li>
</ul>
<%= link_to t('error.button'), :root, :class => 'btn btn-warning btn-lg btn-dark' %>
```

Not sure what else to do here. What am i missing?

Comment: curious, why a format is `png`?

Comment: To be honest i have no idea!

Comment: is this being called by render in a view somewhere?  Can you post the view code that is calling to that?  Also, did it work previously and now it is broke?

Comment: I am rendering a partial within the main view. I've included both files view code. Well, looking back at my bug tracker (bugsnag) i noticed it's been happening for the past month, (guess getting more email alerts would be good), but regardless it used to work, now doesnt. Cannot seem to track down what changed, or what broke it.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are getting a 500 error getting a png image. So your application tries to redirect to your `internal_server_error` action, but it fails to find an `internal_server_error.png` file.

Search your views for outdated `img` tags or `image_tag` calls, and your css for `url()` with png images, and remove or update them.